# Hashtables Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, hashtable

I am currently doing an assignment and can't get my head around what is wanted in the store function in the PrefixTable class.  If anyone could offer some advice on where to start or give me a gentle push in the right direction, that would be much appreciated.

```
class PrefixItem(object):

    '''Stores a prefix:possibles pair.

    >>> p = PrefixItem('th', SortedFrequencyList())
    >>> p.possibles.add('e', 40)
    >>> p.possibles.add('o', 10)
    >>> p
    {th: ({e: 40}, {o: 10})}'''

    def __init__(self, prefix, possibles):

        '''Initialises a new PrefixItem with the given letter `prefix` and
        SortedFrequencyList of `possibles`.'''

        self.prefix = prefix
        self.possibles = possibles

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.prefix)

    def __repr__(self):
        return ('{' + self.prefix + ': ' + str(self.possibles) + '}')


class PrefixTable(object):

    '''A simple hash table for storing prefix:possible combinations using 
    PrefixItems internally.'''

    def __init__(self, slots):

        '''Initialises the PrefixTable with a number of `slots`. The table cannot
        store more items than the number of slots specified here.'''

        self.data = [None] * slots

    def store(self, prefix, possibles):

        '''Stores the given letter `prefix` and list of `possibles` (a 
        SortedFrequencyList) in the hash table using a PrefixItem. If the
        item is successfully stored in the table, this method returns 
        True, otherwise (for example, if there is no more room left in the 
        table) it returns False.

        >>> p = PrefixTable(1)
        >>> p.store('th', SortedFrequencyList())
        True
        >>> p
        [{th: ()}]
        >>> p.store('ca', SortedFrequencyList())
        False'''
```

Comment: I reformatted your code to correct the indentation problems.  Please look it over to make sure I did it properly.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, that looks much better :)

Comment: In the example given in the doc string for `store`, mentally replace `>>> p` by `>>> p.data`. That output (`[{th: ()}]`) is what the `data` attribute should look like after the first element is stored. Try implementing that first.

Comment: Thanks :) But my next question is, how do I know how big I am suppose to initialise the hashtable (PrefixTable) as?

Comment: @Mikey you initialize the size however you want.  In the example in the docstring it is initialized with a size of 1.

Comment: I'm going in circles here :/ Don't suppose you could maybe jump in a chatroom and give me a quick run down @sberry?

Comment: Sure I could.  Where to?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101638/room-for-mogsdad-and-jeeped @sberry

Comment: @sberry Would it be possible to jump into that chat room again just for a few minutes? Thanks